# How to use enums in below situation in swift?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I have a variable **selectedValue:Int** with possible value = 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5.

and depending on that i want to show labeltext as "ok"/ "not good"/ "bad"/ "very good"/ "good"

currently i am using switch case. but i would like to do it in a bettr way say using enums. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating an `enum` with an `Int` rawValue starting from 1 and making it conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, then displaying its `description` property on the label.

```
enum SelectedValue: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case bad = 1, notGood, ok, good, veryGood

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .bad:
            return "bad"
        case .notGood:
            return "not good"
        case .ok:
            return "ok"
        case .good:
            return "good"
        case .veryGood:
            return "very good"
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let intValue = 4
let selectedValue = SelectedValue(rawValue: intValue)
label.text = selectedValue?.description ?? "No value selected"
```

Comment: Pasztor, thanks alot! so i have a variable level = 1/2/3/4/5 depending on users selection. so how do i set the text = good/bad/ok/good/verygood depending on the variable level

Comment: @j.krissa check my updated answer with an example. Also note that I changed the name of the `enum` to `SelectedValue` since types should follow the UpperCamelCase naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum and give all cases raw values like this:

```
enum selectedValue: String {
    case one = "bad"
    case two = "not good"
    case three = "ok"
    case four = "good"
    case five = "very good"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. You can't name `enum` cases using numbers.